# Reading SSL Connection Data

Tags: ssl, header

Please find the following description i read about starting an HTTPS connection

*"1.  A client starts a HTTPS connection with the bank by 
visiting the bank’s login web page. The detail of HTTPS 
connection is described as follows: 
(1)  P says ‘Hello’ to S: As the beginning step, cipher 
configuration that documents the available cipher 
algorithms on P as well as a random generated number RC 
are sent to S. 
(2)  S says ‘Hello’ to P: S reviews the configuration and sends 
back its cipher choices together with the bank’s certificate, 
a RS, and a client digital certificate request. "*

My question is how we can get the values of **Rc** or **Rs** that is send on this connection?.
I need to find this, to create a hash result.{H(RC,RS)}PKc.
Please reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to get into HTTPS details (unless you want to learn how SSL works) cause any HTTPS client will hide everything for you. For a simple explanation of how SSL works you can read the [introductory articles about SSL](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/articles/65-184.php) on our site.

Comment: I`m trying to implement a new method of Security in Online banking. So i need custom encryption patterns on done using the random numbers exchanged by the Server and client while handshaking. i want to retrieve those values. is there any way to do this??

Comment: @Mr.K the way depends on the SSL library used. I doubt that any library lets you retrieve them, but if you use OpenSSL, you can modify it's source code in order to extract those numbers. In any case the task is non-trivial and quite sophisticated.